# Plex service cannot start

Tags: 18.04, server, services, plex

I have tried to install Plex media server on my Ubuntu 18.04 Server edition using this method:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/

But the command `sudo apt install plexmediaserver` failed and suggested, that I instead used snap. Snap worked but `systemctl` was unable to locate the service, so I used `snap` again to remove and instead I installed with `wget` and `dkpg`.

This worked but when I try to startup the service, it crash right away:

```
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has failed.

--

-- The result is RESULT.


    jan 31 11:07:12 server1804 sudo[2235]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    jan 31 11:07:22 server1804 sudo[2271]: admin1804 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib/plexmediaserver ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status plexmediaserver
    jan 31 11:07:22 server1804 sudo[2271]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin1804(uid=0)
    jan 31 11:07:26 server1804 sudo[2271]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 sudo[2274]: admin1804 : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib/plexmediaserver ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start plexmediaserver
    jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 sudo[2274]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by admin1804(uid=0)
    jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
    jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server.



-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has failed

-- Defined-By: systemd

-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

When I run `sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver` I get:

```
plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2021-01-31 11:07:10 CET; 2h 54min ago 

Process: 2246 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_VENDOR="$(grep ^NAME= /etc/os-release | awk -F= "{pr Process: 2238 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p Main PID: 2246 (code=dumped, signal=ILL) – CNR 17 hours ago

jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart. 

jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3. 

jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server. 

jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly. 

jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I suspect, that there is still something left from the first installation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you install Plex? `https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-plex-media-server-ubuntu-18-04`

Comment: I first tried a method, that didn't work but screen-feedback suggested, that I used snap instead. I tried and it installed without problems, but systemctl was unable to detect it. I then removed again with snap and instead used wget and dpkg. I suspect, that there still are something left from first installation because of this:

Comment: sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver

● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sun 2021-01-31 11:07:10 CET; 2h 54min ago
  Process: 2246 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_VENDOR="$(grep ^NAME= /etc/os-release | awk -F= "{pr
  Process: 2238 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkdir -p
 Main PID: 2246 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Comment: jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server.
jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

Comment: jan 31 11:07:10 server1804 systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server.

jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.

jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.

jan 31 11:07:31 server1804 systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server.

Comment: You are correct: You must clean up all your failed attempts before trying again. "*I first tried a method*" is vague. Your question should explain which method, and link to whatever instructions you were following. Please do not dump random output into a comment -- edit your Question instead. Comments are intended to help you improve your question and to help you make it answerable, not for conversation.

Comment: The first method did not install anything, but I have put it in the question now

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]